# What units of measurement are "rows" and "cols" in `@Html.TextAreaFor`?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

While I was able to find a code example of how to use [Text Area Extensions for the TextAreaFor HtmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493070(v=vs.118).aspx), I have still been unable to find any definitions of the units of measurement for "rows" and "cols".

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RelationshipToGrowth, 
      new { rows=10, cols=40, @class="form-control" })
```

If I interpret the parameters literally, I would say that "rows is the number of rows" and "cols is the number of columns", but it does not help me to relate how that translates to presentation on a webpage.

Are the units in pixels? A ratio? Some other unit?

Update: I found [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) but it simply repeats the literal interpretation I took. For example, "Defines the number of columns in a textarea."

So I guess the question is, **how wide is a column** and **how tall is a row**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit of measurement for `rows` is "visible lines":

> The number of visible text lines for the control.

The unit of measurement for `cols` is "average character widths":

> The visible width of the text control, in average character widths. If it is specified, it must be a positive integer. If it is not specified, the default value is 20 (HTML5).

Quotes above from [MDN's `<textarea>` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

Comment: So if I were to think of it in CSS terms, a textarea "row" could relate to the "line height".  There is no explicit CSS unit for a character width, but a common tactic is to define CSS width in terms of "ems".  Does that sound like I'm on the right track?

Comment: Sounds like a good rule of thumb, but I would experiment with creating a textarea and setting the line-height to different values and see if it gets taller and setting the font-size using ems and see if it gets wider.

Comment: I'm using Twitter bootstrap and see that while I see the rows and cols parameters reach the rendered webpage, the text areas are not as wide and tall as I would expect.

Comment: Yeah, I whipped up [a jsfiddle with a experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/qujfjuge/) and it looks like height works like I would think, but width is a different story. That's the devil of "average" :)

Comment: There are two units of measurement that correspond to character width: `ch` ("Average character advance of a narrow glyph in the element’s font, as represented by the “0” (ZERO, U+0030) glyph.") and `ic` ("Average character advance of a full width glyph in the element’s font, as represented by the “水” (CJK water ideograph, U+6C34) glyph."). `ch` seems to be closest to the value used in my very limited testing: https://jsfiddle.net/u03dbxc4/1/, as long as both are using the same, monospaced font.